# Which port should I be using when using express on cPanel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cpanel

I've been trying to use nodeJS on cPanel, but I can only seem to access pages sent via 'vanilla' nodeJS.

The default app.js file works fine and displays the message in the browser:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
        version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
        response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(response);
});
server.listen();
```

However, simple express code like this doesn't work:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

The server will log that it's listening, but going to the same page as before (and adding :3000) results in a 404.

The port is also falling back to 3000, so `process.env.PORT` isn't set. This makes me think it could be a port issue.

I've tried redirecting the port in a .htaccess file, with no luck.

Does anyone know why the standard express code isn't working/what port I'm supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure the port through `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

where `XXXX` is your desired port.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question, but I've already tried this with no luck. The .htaccess file is in the root of the node.js application, should it be anywhere else?

Comment: Should be in the directory that www points to. With other words, in the path which you configured nginx/apache to serve from.

Comment: I've tried putting it in that folder too (in the same .htaccess file passenger is using), but this results in a 503 error.

Comment: that means there's an error in your .htaccess file, a typo or something generally wrong in it.